# Compare register with item at the top of the stack?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Is it possible to compare a register with the item at the top of the stack, without poping it first?

EG this way I can do it but I have to pop the value first:

```
push 1
pop ax
cmp ax,1
jz equal
```

Is is possible to do it without modifying the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the 8086 specifically (rather than the x86 family) then no, I don't believe there was a non-direct-register mode that used the stack pointer.

The basic options were:

```
                [BX]  [SI]
<displacement>   or    or
                [BP]  [DI]
```

Of course, you *could* transfer the stack pointer to `BP` if you weren't using it for anything else and then use that:

```
mov  bp, sp
mov  ax, [bp]
; now check ax
```

or, if you didn't mind the stack being changed for a very short period of time (but watch out if interrupts may cause you problems, they may fire between the `pop` and `push`):

```
pop  ax
push ax
; now check ax
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very start of any asm exe you declare a memory block to record the top of the stack

```
 STAK dw[0]
```

and use bx to store the top of the stack, sp

```
 mov bx,STAK
 mov [bx],sp
```

Then use bx to compare with any register when comparing is needed, bx is a pointing register

```
 mov bx,[STAK]
 cmp ax,[bx]
```

You can use bp instead of bx if you want

Answer (score 0):

If using an x86 family processor (80386 and up) in 32-bit protected mode, comparing the top of the stack to AX without using PUSH or POP is quite easy as all the general purpose registers can be used as a base index.

```
CMP    AX, [ESP]      ; compare top of stack with AX
CMP   EAX, [ESP]      ; compare top of stack with EAX
```

From "Table 2-1. 16-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte" of the IA32 Instruction Set Reference manual, the following combinations can be used.

```
[BX] + displacment
[BP] + displacement
[SI] + displacement
[DI] + displacement
[BX + SI] + displacement
[BX + DI] + displacement
[BP + SI] + displacement
[BP + DI] + displacement
```

Unfortunately, using the stack register is not one of them in 16-bit mode (such as on the 8086).  This means that to access the top of the stack without using PUSH or POP, you must first move the contents of the SP register to either BX, BP, SI or DI and then use one of those registers to access the top element on the stack.

There are a couple of gotchas of which you must be aware.  You must either be sure that the register's default segment register matches the stack segment register SS, or you must explicitly force the use of a particular segment register with the register.  It has been quite some time since I've done any 16-bit coding so some of those rules escape me at the moment.  The manuals will definitely contain them.

The BP register does use the stack segment SS by default.  It is also used in creating a stack frame inside routines and for indexing to get parameters passed on the stack as well as local stack variables.

```
PUSH    BP        ; These two lines are often used to create the stack
MOV     BP, SP    ; at the start of a routine
SUB     SP, #     ; Carve space on the stack for local stack variables
```

A typical stack frame may look like ...

```
[BP + 6]    ; 16-bit parameter
[BP + 4]    ; 16-bit parameter
[BP + 2]    ; return address IP saved on stack
[BP + 0]    ; saved BP on stack
[BP - 2]    ; 16-bit local variable on the stack
[BP - 4]    ; 16-bit local variable on the stack
```

Hope this helps.